# Create PDF/UA document using PDFBox, C#

Tags: c#, accessibility, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBOx to create accessible PDF document.How can I create PDF/UA document? 
tried with below code. But it is created PDF/A document.

```
XMPSchemaPDFAId pdfaid = new XMPSchemaPDFAId(xmp);
xmp.addSchema(pdfaid);
pdfaid.setConformance("B");
pdfaid.setPart(1);
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a PAC 2 verifiable PDF using PDFBox 1.8.9? If it is possible, How can I resolve PAC 2 error,  "PDF/UA identifier missing"?

Comment: Any update on this?